# One images catalog between two apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two application: CMS and site itself. In the cms admin can upload images and they saves on filesystem (path: D:\Images).
In the second app I need to show this image.
This is not work:

```
<img src="D:\Images\e6895b06-38fe-4ac4-96b9-98037910ac5b.Jpeg">
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use internet URLs instead of disk URLs.
If your images are stored in a folder that does not belong to your CMS application you need to create a virtual folder in IIS and point it to your image folder on disk.
Then you can use something like

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/e6895b06-38fe-4ac4-96b9-98037910ac5b.Jpeg")" />
```

This uses the MVC URL helper to generate a fully qualified URL for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the images in database ? If you do not want to use the database - the images should be in subfolder in your site. So you have to change their location.